TypeError for .iloc while trying to get mean
I'm encountering a type error in my Python code when trying to process DST data from a URL using Pandas. Here's the relevant snippet of my code:
url_jan = "https://wdc.kugi.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dst_realtime/202401/dst2401.for.request"
data_jan = pd.read_csv(url_jan, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

data_jan.drop(columns=[1, 26], inplace=True)
columns = ['Date'] + list(range(1, 25))

data_jan.columns = columns

data_jan['Mean'] = data_jan.iloc[:,1:25].mean(axis=1)
df_mean = data_jan[['Date', 'Mean']]

What I Tried: I attempted to read DST data from a URL using Pandas, dropped unnecessary columns, and assigned column names where the first column should be 'Date' and subsequent columns should be integers from 1 to 24.
Expected Outcome: I expected the column names to be assigned correctly without any errors, allowing me to compute the mean across columns 1 to 24 and create a new DataFrame (df_mean) containing 'Date' and 'Mean' columns.
Actual Result: However, during the assignment of column names (data_jan.columns = columns), a type error occurred: "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not 'int') to str". This error prevented the column names from being assigned as expected.

Your table contains a non-numeric trailing row:
data_jan.iloc[:,1:25].tail()

      1    2   3         4    5      6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14   15   16   17    18    19    20    21   22   23    24
27   13   14  13        17   15     12  13.0  14.0  10.0  16.0  19.0  13.0  17.0  12.0  8.0  7.0  5.0   2.0  -3.0  -7.0 -10.0 -7.0 -1.0  -2.0
28    0   -5  -6        -4   -6     -5  -7.0  -9.0 -10.0  -6.0  -7.0 -10.0  -6.0   2.0 -1.0 -4.0 -5.0 -10.0 -10.0 -10.0  -8.0  1.0  7.0  10.0
29    9    8   2        -2   -5     -9 -11.0 -14.0 -14.0 -12.0  -8.0  -8.0  -8.0  -6.0 -6.0 -8.0 -7.0  -8.0  -9.0  -9.0  -4.0  3.0  1.0  -2.0
30   -1    1  -4        -9   -7     -6  -7.0  -6.0  -9.0 -10.0  -8.0  -4.0  -2.0  -2.0 -3.0 -6.0 -6.0  -7.0  -7.0 -11.0 -10.0 -3.0 -2.0  -1.0
31  Tue  Apr  30  15:05:33  UTC  2024]   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN

Get rid of it:
data_jan = data_jan.head(-1)

data_jan['Mean'] = data_jan.iloc[:,1:25].astype(float).mean(axis=1)
df_mean = data_jan[['Date', 'Mean']]

You could also ignore this trailing row while importing from your URL with the skipfooter option of read_csv:
data_jan = pd.read_csv(url_jan, sep='\s+', header=None,
                       skipfooter=1, engine='python')

Output df_mean:
                Date       Mean
0   DST2401*01RRX020  -4.125000
1   DST2401*02RRX020 -10.458333
2   DST2401*03RRX020  -4.083333
3   DST2401*04RRX020  -9.958333
4   DST2401*05RRX020 -11.833333
5   DST2401*06RRX020  -5.416667
6   DST2401*07RRX020   0.541667
7   DST2401*08RRX020   7.583333
8   DST2401*09RRX020   4.208333
9   DST2401*10RRX020  -0.166667
10  DST2401*11RRX020  -8.625000
11  DST2401*12RRX020  -3.083333
12  DST2401*13RRX020  -2.625000
13  DST2401*14RRX020  -9.083333
14  DST2401*15RRX020  -6.208333
15  DST2401*16RRX020  -3.125000
16  DST2401*17RRX020   0.666667
17  DST2401*18RRX020  -3.208333
18  DST2401*19RRX020 -10.041667
19  DST2401*20RRX020  -6.541667
20  DST2401*21RRX020  -1.583333
21  DST2401*22RRX020   3.208333
22  DST2401*23RRX020  -1.875000
23  DST2401*24RRX020  -0.791667
24  DST2401*25RRX020   4.333333
25  DST2401*26RRX020  -0.291667
26  DST2401*27RRX020  -1.875000
27  DST2401*28RRX020   7.916667
28  DST2401*29RRX020  -4.541667
29  DST2401*30RRX020  -5.291667
30  DST2401*31RRX020  -5.416667

